# Symfony 2 - create admin pages

Tags: php, symfony, admin

First of all, I'm new in Symfony2 and I'm developing an app with it.
This is a Portfolio, here's my hierarchy:

**I want to create my own back office.**

/src
----/Antoine
--------/PortfolioBundle
------------/Controller
----------------ProjectsController.php
------------/Resources
----------------/config
--------------------routing.yml
--------------------routing_admin.yml ?
--------/UserBundle
------------/Controller
----------------DefaultController.php
------------/Resources
----------------/config
--------------------routing.yml
--------------------routing_admin.yml ?

Should I :
- Put admin Actions in each controllers (ex: ProjectsController:addAction())
- Create an AdminController in each bundles
- Create a Bundle named AdminBundle (I don't like it)

If I want to prefix all admin routes by /admin, then should I create a admin_routing.yml in each bundle and include it in each routing.yml of each bundle with prefix /admin ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should I :

- Put admin Actions in each controllers (ex: ProjectsController:addAction())

*No. That would give trouble with your method-names and it is confusing*

- Create an AdminController in each bundles

*Yes or more then one AdminController. For example:*

- *DefaultAdminController*
- *ProjectsAdminController*

*etc*

- Create a Bundle named AdminBundle (I don't like it)

*If you directly create admin pages and you reuse your Entities and maybe a few other classes then your AdminBundle wouldn't be independent as it should.*

Besides that you could take a look at the [Sonata admin bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/index.html). Here you can learn how they built an AdminBundle that is totally decoupled

Comment: You don't give any reason for saying "no" to creating an AdminBundle. I don't really use Symfony, I'm just wondering what is wrong with using an AdminBundle. To me, it seems to make more sense to wrap the entire admin section in its own neatly contained bundle with its own controllers, views, etc. Business logic can be stored outside of both bundles.

Comment: You are right. The main reason is that if you directly create admin pages and you reuse your Entities and maybe a few other classes then your AdminBundle wouldn't be independent as it should. That's why i also pointed to Sonata admin bundle. Here you can learn how they built an AdminBundle that is totally decoupled.

Comment: Good point. I guess in this sort of situation the admin bundle is specifically designed for the app and is non-transferrable to another app (assuming OP is not trying to create a generic admin plugin, as Sonata is).

Comment: @BadHorsie if that would be your choice than nobody will stop you to do so. I did that too on my first Symfony project several years ago but i still regret it. All Different bundles that you are working on makes a long list of directories and gives you a lot of search-work. And every time you have to type a name of a twig template or an entity or a controller you have to think about the bundle name. My  advice: don't :-)

Comment: @Frankbeen I feel confortable with the idea of creating several AdminController in each Bundles where I need admin pages, Thank you !

Comment: @Frankbeen Yes, sorry - to clarify I am agreeing that your advice is good.